# How to do callback + update div tag in javascript

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with pages where the content is loaded into divs from client via JavaScript/jQuery/JSON. The loaded content contains a-tags with references to a function that updates server side values, then redirects to reload of entire page even though.

I wish to replace the a-tags with 'something' to still call a server-side function, then reload the div only.

What is the 'right' way of doing this?

All comments welcome.

This is as far as I got so far. `getResponseCell()` returns a td-tag filled with a-tag.
I've mangled Glens suggestion into the `.click()` addition, but it just calls the `onClickedEvent`...

Code sample:

```
    onClickedEvent=function()
    {
        return false;
    }

    getResponseCell=function(label, action, eventId)
    {
        tmpSubSubCell=document.createElement("td");
        link = document.createElement("A");
        link.appendChild( document.createTextNode( label));
        link.setAttribute("href", "/EventResponse/"+ action + "/" + eventId);
        //link.setAttribute("href", "#divContentsEventList");
        //link.setAttribute("onclick", "onClickedEvent(); return false;");
        link.setAttribute("className", "eventResponseLink");
        
        
        link.click(onClickedEvent());
            
        // link=jQuery("<A>Kommer<A/>").attr("href", "/EventResponse/"+ action + "/" + eventId).addClass("eventResponseLink");
        // link.appendTo(tmpSubSubCell);
        tmpSubSubCell.appendChild(link);
        
        return tmpSubSubCell;
    }
```

---

And the solution that worked for me looks like this:

```
    onClickedEvent=function(event, actionLink)
    {
            event.preventDefault(); 

            $("eventListDisplay").load(actionLink);

            refreshEventList();                

            return false;
    }

    getResponseCell=function(label, action, eventId)
    {
        tmpSubSubCell=document.createElement("td");
        link = document.createElement("A");
        link.setAttribute("id",action + eventId);
        link.appendChild( document.createTextNode( label));
        actionLink = "/EventResponse/"+ action + "/" + eventId;
        link.setAttribute("href", actionLink);
        className = "eventResponseLink"+ action + eventId;
        link.setAttribute("className", className);

        $('a.'+className).live('click', function (event)
            {
                onClickedEvent(event,$(this).attr('href'));
            });

        tmpSubSubCell.appendChild(link);
        
        return tmpSubSubCell;
    }
```

Comment: for a-tags you mean `<a onclick="" >` tag!?

Comment: If I add the line below (which is what you suggest?) I still do not get a call to the onClickedEvent function (or at least the debugger does not stop at breakpoint in function)...

    link.setAttribute("onclick", "onClickedEvent(); return false;");

Comment: Have you got an more examples of the response you get or just some more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without really seeing more information.....

If you're a's are being added to the DOM after the initial page load, you cannot use the usual `click()` or `bind()` methods in jQuery; this is because these methods only bind the events to those elements that are registered in the DOM at the time the methods are called. `live()` on the other hand, will register the event for all current, and future elements (using the event bubbling mechanism in Javascript).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.eventResponseLink').live('click', function (event) {
        var self = $(this);

        self.closest('div').load('/callYourServerSideFunction.asp?clickedHref=' + self.attr('href'));

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

We're using `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action of the a-tag being executed; e.g. reloading or changing page.

**Edit:** The issue won't be caused by that. That's the power of jQuery; being able to bind the same event to multiple elements. Check your HTML; maybe you're missing a closing `</a>` somewhere? Maybe your binding the event in a location that gets called multiple times? Each time `.live()` gets called, it will add ANOTHER event handler to all matched elements. It only needs to be bound once on page load.

jQuery provides loads of way for you to select the elements; check out the [list](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors). Looking at your link variable, it looks like all your links have a href starting with `/EventResponse/`; so you can use `$('a[href^=/EventResponse/]')` as the selector instead.

Comment: Almost there ;-). My js function gets activated when clicking the link and the page does not refresh. So far so good! However it seems that the event handler is called a number of times - I'm inserting a number of the a-tags all with same class and suspect that is the culprit? The class is used for my css formatting - is there another way of selecting the link I've just created? Using the 'link' variable in above code listing?

Comment: I got through! Thanks for all your help (aSeptik and Glen too),

Answer (score 1):

We need code to give you a proper answer, but the following code will catch the click of an a-tag, and reload the div that it's inside:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        //call server-side function
        var parentDiv = $(this).parents("div:first");
        $(parentDiv).load("getContentOfThisDiv.asp?id=" + $(parentDiv).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

In the above code, when a link is clicked, the div that this the link is inside will be loaded with the response of the call to the asp file. The id of the div is sent to the file as a parameter.

Comment: I've added my code to the question. I didn't manage to follow the $("a").click suggestion very well.
Also, instead of loading the div tag with contents of a server call, could I just make the server call, then afterwards activate a function in my script (not included in listing)?